# Execute Ajax callback after form validation Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

I have form in Drupal 8, in hook_form_alter I'm trying to make Ajax request.

```
function helloworld_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_id == 'contact_message_feedback_form') {

$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
  'wrapper' => 'form_wrapper',
  'callback' => 'custom_callback',
  'event' => 'click',
  'progress' => [
  'type' => 'throbber',
  'message' => 'Veryfieng'],
  );  

$form['test_selection'] = [
  '#type' => 'hidden', 
  '#prefix' => '<div id="form_wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#weight' => 100,
];
  }
} 



 function custom_callback($form, &$form_state) {
   $output = array();

   $output['#markup'] = 'Thank you! Your message has been sent!';

   return $output;
 }
```

This works but the whole validation function is ignored. 
How can I validate the form before custom_callback() is called?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom Ajax callback, try following code, it would call submitForm() method of your Form and thus call validateForm() method as well before calling submitForm() -

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#attributes' => array (
     'class' => array (
         'use-ajax-submit'
     ), 
  ),
  '#ajax' => array(
     'wrapper' => 'form_wrapper',
  )
);
```

In short it would submit your form through Ajax.